# Is it no longer possible to drill down Events in GA4?

Tags: google-analytics

I have a multipage form that users fill out.  The form is multipage, but the html page remains the same.  My current analytics (UA) tracks the pages as users click next and move through the form.

I recreated the same events in Google Tag Manager for G4 and I can see them in real-time, i.e, "User clicked page 2 of 3". However, I cannot find them for anything other than real-time.  When I go to **Engagement>Events** I see the Event Name. But when I click on the Event Name to drill down through the steps in the event, I don't see any details.  Just the Real Time option on the right of the page.

Is this no longer an option, or do I have the event misconfigured?

Answer (score 0):

According to this article https://www.rootandbranchgroup.com/ga4-event-parameters/ it appears that if I want to see any of the event parameters, I'll need to create a custom report.  I'll need to spend more time experimenting with creating this report and then I'll modify this answer with more detail.

Comment: Did you ever figure it out? I'm in the same boat..

Comment: @Derrick, not really.  I ended up having to create my own events in GA4.

Answer (score 0):

They have removed content drilldown in GA4. Used to be that you can see what keywords they use to find your pages.